# How Can I configure n3 store for sparql end point?

Tags: node.js, rdf, sparql, rdfstore, n3

Hey I am working on a project of Nodejs. How can I use/config n3 (https://www.npmjs.com/package/n3) store for communicate with end point rdf-storage. In my rdf storage I can completly management (CRUD) triples.

Only missing part for me is communication between n3 store and sparql end point.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

See this [response on the Jena Users Mailing list](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/jena-users/201502.mbox/%3CCAM0wMfRs6fW9axUr_Jo%2B%2B%3DafX9YRhkzLqTpt84eHFe8WMmnG-Q%40mail.gmail.com%3E)